What is the value of $\int_{3}^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(\ln(\ln(x))^2)}dx$?
If I calculate the value of $\int\limits_{3}^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(\ln(\ln(x))^2)}dx$ by wolfram alpha it says $\approx 10.663$. However, If I do it by hand via a substitution and integration by parts I get a different value:
\begin{align*}
&\int\limits_{3}^\beta\frac{1}{x\ln(x)(\ln(\ln(x))^2)}dx=\int\limits_{e^3}^{e^\beta}\frac{1}{y(\ln(y)^2)}dy=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(y)^2}\Big|_{e^3}^{e^\beta}+2\int\limits_{e^3}^{e^\beta}\frac{\ln(y)}{y(\ln(y)^3)}dy=\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\Big|_{e^3}^{e^\beta}+2\int\limits_{e^3}^{e^\beta}\frac{1}{y(\ln(y)^2)}dy\\
&\implies -\int\limits_{e^3}^{e^\beta}\frac{1}{y(\ln(y)^2)}dy=\frac{1}{\beta}-\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}If we let $\beta\to\infty$ we get $\int\limits_{3}^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(\ln(\ln(x))^2)}dx=\frac{1}{3}$. Where is my mistake?

Let $I = \int\limits_{3}^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(\ln(\ln(x))^2)}dx$.
Let $u = \ln x \implies x = e^u \implies dx = e^u ~du$.  Then:
$$I = \int\limits_{\ln 3}^\infty \frac{1}{e^uu(\ln(u)^2)}e^u ~du$$
$$= \int\limits_{\ln 3}^\infty \frac{1}{u(\ln(u)^2)} ~du$$
Let $v = \ln u \implies u = e^v \implies du = e^v ~dv$.
$$I = \int\limits_{\ln \ln 3}^\infty \frac{1}{e^v(v^2)} e^v ~dv$$
$$= \int\limits_{\ln \ln 3}^\infty \frac{1}{v^2} ~dv$$
$$= \left[\frac{-1}{v}\right]_{v=\ln\ln 3}^{v\to\infty}$$
$$= 0 - \left(\frac{-1}{\ln\ln 3}\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{\ln\ln 3}\approx 10.63$$
It seems that your mistake was that you converted the bounds wrong when you did your substitution. Note that I have $\ln 3$ where you have $e^3$.

Let $u(x)=\ln(\ln(x))$. The function $u$ est differentiable on $(e,+\infty)$ and, for all $x>e$ :
$$u'(x)=\frac{\frac1x}{\ln(x)}=\frac1{x\ln(x)}$$
Hence :
$$\left(\frac1{u(x)}\right)'=-\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)^2}=-\frac1{x\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))}$$
This make the calculation straightforward :
$$\int_3^{+\infty}\frac1{x\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))}\,dx=\left[-\frac1{\ln(\ln(x))}\right]_3^{+\infty}=\frac1{\ln(\ln(3))}$$
